# How to use multiple async/await functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an error when I deploy my functions : `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token saveLastReview`.

I need to get some document values, then call a url request, then set data in my document.

```
async function getValue() {

  try {
    var doc = await admin.firestore().collection('mycollec').doc('mydoc').get();
    var data = doc.data()

    return data;

  } catch(e) {

    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }   
}

async function saveLastReview(authorName) {

  var rating = "4";
  var title = "my title";
  var content = "my content";

  let data = {
      rating : rating,
      title: title,
      content: content
  };

  try {
    var doc = await admin.firestore().collection('mycollec').doc('mydoc').collection('reviews').doc(authorName).set(data);
    return doc;

  } catch(e) {

    console.log(e);
    return null;
  } 
}


app.get('/hello-world',  async(req, res) => {

  var data = await getValue();


  if (data === null) {
      request("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=284882215/sortBy=mostRecent/json", function (error, response, body) {

        //code to get authorname from the response

        var result = await saveLastReview(authorname);

        //check if doc was set correctly
        //do something

      })
  }

  return res.status(200).send("sent !");

});
module.exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I'm not very familiar with async/await. I don't find the problem.

Comment: What browser are you on? `async` `await` might just not be supported there.

Comment: Consider using the request-promise module to get a API that's more friendly for promises.  What you have now has a significant problem with the response being sent before the HTTP request completes, which means that it might never complete (because of the way Cloud Functions works).

Comment: @Grabofus This code isn't running in a browser - it's running on node.js in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your callback in the `request` is missing the `async` keyword. Might lead to the error you are seeing, which relates to the line where you `await`, which means nothing in a non-async function.

Should probably be :

```
//...   

request("https://itunes.apple.com/...", async function (error, response, body) {

//...
```

EDIT: as mentioned in the comment, that is maybe not it. But I also notice that `saveLastReview` is an `async` function itself, and I don't know how `async` function behave when they are `await`ed. Maybe another avenue of investigation if what I mentioned first doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: `await` in a non-`async` function will end with a _"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators"_

Comment: Ah yes! So actually maybe the problem is that OP is `await`ing an `async` function...